# Textbox empty after submitting

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

How can I keep the value of textboxes after submitting a form?
When I press the submit button the values dissapear.

What I want is that the values don't dissapear from the textbox after pressing submit button.

Comment: HTTP is a [_stateless protocol_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) , you need to make use of sessions or cookies for your scenario and if you search on stackoverflow , you will get tonnes of articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since HTTP is a stateless protocol so it lost previous data from the submitted form.

You can use session or you can do it like this:

```
<input name="email" value="<?php isset($_REQUEST['email']) ? $_REQUEST['email'] : '' ?>">
```

it will check if value exists in the super global `$_REQUEST` if exists then echoing it as value of the input field. set like this for all input field.

Answer (score 1):

in PHP you can do

```
<input type="text" name="fieldName" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fieldName']) ? $_POST['fieldName'] : '' ?>" />
```

Comment: it's just an example and according to the POST or GET method the above example will be applied. I have also used here name="fieldName" and input type="text". so there might be multiple questions. But we are not here to argument and if you concentrate only how people will get help that would be better for you as well as for others.